# EF + generic repository + loading related entity: only explicit load works

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I have two simple POCO classes; I'm trying to get the `MyY` property below hydrated with the an instance of `Y`. I've tried a number of ways to do this, and think I might be missing something obvious or simple.

```
public class X
{
     public int Id { get; set;}
     public virtual Y MyY { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     // ...
}
```

I've turned lazy loading off via this call in my subclass of `DbContext`'s constructor:

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

When retrieving an `X` I have tried

```
context.Set<X>.Include("MyY").FirstOrDefault(x => ....);
```

which did not work. I tried

```
var result = context.Set<X>.FirstOrDefault(x => ....);
context.Entry(result).Reference("MyY").Load();
```

which works, but requires two round-trips to the database. I tried

```
context.Set<X>.Select(x => new { X = x, Y = x.MyY }).FirstOrDefault(x => ...);
```

which also works, but "weakens" my model (ordinarily projecting to a new type is not so bad, but the "shape" of these EF POCOs works perfectly for the DTOs I'll be sending through WCF later).

I finally tried removing `virtual` from the `MyY` property as suggested in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851169/how-to-eagerly-load-a-many-to-many-relationship-with-the-entity-framework-code-fi/5851193#5851193) to another question, but that had no effect at all.

Finally, I want to use the generic repository pattern. What I have ended up with is the following design, shown in part, which supports explicit-load (not preferred) and eager-load *when modified to work properly*. How do I modify it to get the single db round-trip eager-load?

```
public class EFRepository : IRepository
{
    public T Get<T>(Specification<T> specification) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        var result = ApplyEagerLoading(context.Set<T>()).FirstOrDefault(specification.IsMatch);
        ApplyPostQueryLoading(new List<T> { result });
        return result;
    }

    // doesn't really seem to work yet...
    private DbSet<T> ApplyEagerLoading<T>(DbSet<T> set) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        var ls = loadSpecs.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), () => new List<LoadSpec>());
        foreach (var spec in ls.Where(s => !s.ExplicitLoad))
            set.Include(spec.PropertyName);
        return set;
    }

    // works, but wrong on so many levels...
    private void ApplyPostQueryLoading<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        var ls = loadSpecs.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), () => new List<LoadSpec>());
        foreach (var e in entities)
            foreach (var spec in ls.Where(s => s.ExplicitLoad))
                if (spec.IsCollection)
                    context.Entry(e).Collection(spec.PropertyName).Load();
                else
                    context.Entry(e).Reference(spec.PropertyName).Load();
    }

    private readonly IDictionary<Type, IList<LoadSpec>> loadSpecs = new Dictionary<Type, IList<LoadSpec>>();

    private class LoadSpec
    {
        internal string PropertyName;
        internal bool ExplicitLoad;
        internal bool IsCollection;
    }
}
```

Example uses:

```
// add a rule to load MyY explicitly
repository.AddLoadRule<X>(x => x.MyY, explicit:true, isCollection:false)
...
var x = repository.Get<X>(new Specification<X>(x => x.Id == 5));

// add a rule to load MyY with X
repository.AddLoadRule<X>(x => x.MyY, explicit:false)
...
// x.MyY will be null! Doesn't work!
var x = repository.Get<X>(new Specification<X>(x => x.Id == 5));
```

#### An Update Based on [The Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601306/ef-generic-repository-loading-related-entity-only-explicit-load-works/6601928#6601928):

It turns out my temp code examples lied (those one-liners above). I had actually cached the result of `.Include` in a local variable but applied the `.FirstOrDefault` against the `.Set<X>` not the result of `.Include`. Here is the fix to `ApplyEagerLoading`, which mirrors what others have suggested in related questions:

```
    private IQueryable<T> ApplyEagerLoading<T>(IEnumerable<T> set) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        var ls = loadSpecs.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), () => new List<LoadSpec>());
        var query = set.AsQueryable();
        return ls.Where(s => !s.ExplicitLoad).Aggregate(query, (current, spec) => current.Include(spec.PropertyName));
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an relation (foreign key relation) between X and Y in modeldesigner and/or database?

Comment: Properties on entities need to be virtual when lazy loading is enabled, otherwise it doesnt matter.

Comment: @Kit: The previous answer you link to was mine, the statement about eager loading was wrong and I removed it - at this point I am not aware of any mechanism to always force eager loading of a particular navigation property by default in Linq to Entities, so you will have to use `Include()` or `Load()` in some form.

Comment: @BrokenGlass - ok no problem. It would be a great way to do it if real!

Comment: @Marcus - there is an FK relationship in the database. FWIW, when I save the aggregate root, the related entity also saves as expected.

Comment: You should start with removing all the repository and especially specification stuff and make the bare query to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
X entity = context.Set<X>().Include(x => x.MyY).FirstOrDefault();
```

IF it doesn't the problem must be elsewhere.

If you need some eager loading strategy check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376421/ef-including-other-entities-generic-repository-pattern/5376637#5376637).

Comment: I tried the expression form of DbSet<T>.Include() and it had the same result. I'm somewhat surprised.

Comment: Take the whole linq query without FirstOrDefault and convert it to DbQuery<X>. Check its ToString method, it should contain generated SQL. Execute the query manually and check results.

Comment: I thought I had the bare queries working. You made me go recheck, and for that, thanks! What I was doing was applying .FirstOrDefault to the Set<X>, not the Set<X>.Include(). In other words, I did do the .Include(), but I basically threw it away (some temp variables and what not as I was playing with the code).